# Перенос кода с vb на с#

Tags: c#

Помогите перенести код с vb на C#

Код vb

```
Private Structure StructExcelNamedRangeAddress
        Public Sheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
        Public Column As Integer
        Public Row As Integer
        Public Cell As Object
    End Structure
Private Function ExcelNamedRangeAddress(ByRef book As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook, Name As String) As StructExcelNamedRangeAddress
    ExcelNamedRangeAddress = New StructExcelNamedRangeAddress
    For Each RangeSearch In book.Names
        If RangeSearch.Name = Name Then
            Try
                ExcelNamedRangeAddress.Sheet = RangeSearch.RefersToRange.cells(0).WorkSheet
                ExcelNamedRangeAddress.Column = RangeSearch.RefersToRange.cells(0).Column
                ExcelNamedRangeAddress.Row = RangeSearch.RefersToRange.cells(0).Row + 1
                ExcelNamedRangeAddress.Cell = ExcelNamedRangeAddress.Sheet.Cells(ExcelNamedRangeAddress.Row, RangeSearch.RefersToRange.cells(0).Column)
                Exit For
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Код c# (что сделал)

```
 private struct StructExcelNamedRangeAddress
        {
            public Worksheet Sheet;
            public int Column;
            public int Row;
            public Object Cell;
        }

    private StructExcelNamedRangeAddress ExcelNamedRangeAddress(Workbook book, string Name)
    {
        StructExcelNamedRangeAddress ExcelNamedRangeAddress;
        foreach (Workbook RangeSearch in book.Names)
        { 
        if (RangeSearch.Name == Name)
            {
                ExcelNamedRangeAddress.Sheet = RangeSearch.RefersToRange.cells(0).WorkSheet;
                ExcelNamedRangeAddress.Column = RangeSearch.RefersToRange.cells(0).Column;
                ExcelNamedRangeAddress.Row = RangeSearch.RefersToRange.cells(0).Row + 1;
                ExcelNamedRangeAddress.Cell = ExcelNamedRangeAddress.Sheet.Cells(ExcelNamedRangeAddress.Row, RangeSearch.RefersToRange.cells(0).Column);
            }
         }
      }
```

ошибка которые я не могу устранить
"Workbook" не содержит определения для "RefersToRange"
Невызываемый член "_Worksheet.Cells" не может использоваться как метод

Ошибка

> Ошибка    CS1061  "Workbook" не содержит определения для "RefersToRange", и не удалось найти доступный метод расширения "RefersToRange", принимающий тип "Workbook" в качестве первого аргумента (возможно, пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку).  ConsoleReport   \ConsoleReport\Program.cs   168 Активный

Comment: есть online-конвертеры, например: http://converter.telerik.com/

Comment: Почти тоже самое и получилось, но ошибки остались теже

Comment: эта ошибка и в VB и в C#?

Comment: в vb работает, ошибки только в c#

Comment: а, да, проблема в том, что в C# `Cells` - это свойство, поэтому к его элементам надо обращаться через `[]`: `RefersToRange.cells(0)` -> `RefersToRange.Cells[0]`

Comment: Вторая ошибка пропала, а вот эта осталась" "Workbook" не содержит определения для "RefersToRange" "

Comment: добавь в вопрос точный текст ошибки

Comment: А где класс?? В котором все будет завернуто...

Comment: Определение для `RefersToRange` находится в интерфейсе `Name`, замените в `foreach (Workbook RangeSearch in book.Names)` `Workbook` на `Name`

Comment: Благадорю  Grundy и Cost все получилось

Comment: @Евгений, добавь тогда свой ответ что и как именно решал